# buildozer fails to compile apk

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

Buildozer fails to compile an apk from a kivy application in ubuntu 13.04 64 bit. Returns:

```
assets/private.mp3: /home/robbie/python/kivy/test2app/.buildozer/android /app/sitecustomize.pyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build.py", line 412, in <module>
make_package(args)
File "build.py", line 336, in make_package
subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name test2app --version 1.0 --package   org.test.myapp --private /home/robbie/python/kivy/test2app/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 21 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
```

Any ideas on how to get this to compile. All dependencies are installed (python2.7, python-virtualenv, git, python-git, openjdk-7-jre, cython) but the build file still crashes. this is the current build of buildozer from github as of 2/6/14 and yes this was run as root.

Comment: Posting partial output won't help you need to post the entire log. Why are you using root? Was there a permissions error? Make sure you have permissions to access the dir the app is in. Using root won't help much if you are using a remote share that is read-only. Regardless; using buildozer doesn't require root.